# How do I create reactive Grafana variables that are based on other variables, all of which are defined in the dashboard settings?

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I am trying to make a dashboard in Grafana, where all the variables are defined in the dashboard settings. Most of these are constants, though I have three input variables in the dashboard that will reactively change several other variables. My issue is that I am unable to define new variables that will reactively change depending on the value of input values.

For instance, suppose I have defined an input variable "input1" that is set to 10. I want to make a new variable "test" = $input1 * 10. When I attempt to do this, I get that test = "$input1 * 10" rather than test = 100.

Even when I use any two constants, eg. "a" = 10 and "b" = 2, if I try to make a new variable "c" = $a*$b, I get that c = "$a*$b" rather than c = 20.

Is there a way to perform calculations like these when defining variables? I am not querying or extracting data from any external data sources - all variables are defined in the dashboard settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grafana can't evaluate calculation of variables. But you can do that in used datasource.

Switch variable to `Query` type and write query, which will be executed by selected datasource and it will return calculated value.

Example for `PostgreSQL` type datasource:

```
SELECT $a*$b
```

Of course not all datasource types can perform this kind of calculations. SQL datasources can do that usually.